# Firebase logEvent String length

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to using firebase, but when I want to logging the most visited url from user by using `logEvent` this show error. Here is the code:

```
Bundle bundle3 = new Bundle();
bundle3.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID,"browser_most_url_bookmarked");
bundle3.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "http://vozforums.com/forumdisplay.php?f=33");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle3);
```

Logcat shows:

> W/FA: Value is too long; discarded. Value kind, name, value length:
>   param, content_type, 42

I can't understande why, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 18):

Yea.. found the issue.

Your this line is causing this log:

```
bundle3.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "http://vozforums.com/forumdisplay.php?f=33");
```

They are talking about [FirebaseAnalytics.Param](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param) class
Your log is also informative. These are some points to focus on:

`Value is too long:` means you are passing somewhat large string than expected.

```
Value kind, name, value length: param, content_type, 42
```

means

```
Kind = Param
Name = content_type
Length = 42
```

> [From Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param) in few words:

```
Param names can be up to 40 characters long
Param values can be up to 100 characters long
```

But your value length is 42 which is larger than maximum supported length of Param value (i.e. 36)

Hence, you are getting that Log. Hope you are clear by now.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. I was unserstand this isssue but if i want to log some url that user usually visited, it seem no way to do that ? Sometime I need to using logEvent with long string data, can I do that?

Comment: Seems like they changed this. In the docs it now says "Param values can be up to 100 characters long." and " Param names can be up to 40 characters long"